# what should I do about limp, spindly pea seedlings?

Tags: peas

I have dwarf pea plants growing in a big pot indoors. It's about a month since I planted them. Most of them are doing just fine, but I've noticed some plants are too limp and spindly to stand up. I don't see any mold on them, the stalks just seem malformed. Maybe it's because I planted the peas too close together? Anyway, I don't know what to do about them. Should water them more? Less? Cut them off at the base? What?

Comment: First, could you please share a photo or two, that helps finding an answer that fits the symptoms. Second, where in the world are you (asking about day length, if you are using grow lights, this may not apply)?

Comment: Peas are vines and will not stand on their own. More light will make for less spindliness.